# Changing Button fonts in C# Windows forms - "Medium" font style is unavailable

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I'm working on a Windows Forms project in C#, and one of the things I have done is create a custom close button.  I discovered that the Marlett font can be used to generate the "X" for the close button, however I want to use the "Medium" Marlett style because "Bold" is too thick.  When I try to select "Medium" in properties it always defaults back to bold.  My button looks like this:

[image]

In properties the font is defined like this:

[image]

If I try to change the property I can select "Medium", but it always defaults back to "Bold":

[image]

In the designer code (which I'm NOT going to change) it looks like this:

[image]

I attempted to change the font at Runtime by doing the following:

```
    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _BtnClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Marlett", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Medium, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(2)));
    }
```

However there is no "Medium" font style available in `System.Drawing.FontStyle`.

How would I force my program to use the "Medium" font style?

Comment: Marlett doesn't have multiple styles or weights. It's just a single font.

Comment: OK, so how do I stop it from displaying as bold?

Comment: You don't. Marlett is just Marlett. It doesn't have any additional weights. "bold" means nothing; that is the default appearance of the font and you can't change it.

Comment: So how do you explain the fact that the "X" button in other windows applications like Chrome or even visual studio looks a lot thinner than in my form?

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't use the Marlett font for those things anymore. For example, compare the maximize/restore icons to the ones that are part of Marlett -- the Windows 10 ones are just boxes, but the Marlett ones have a title bar at the top.

Comment: They draw it. How about you do the same? Not that difficult to draw `x` shape. Also consider, what if the client's machine does not have the `Marlett` font for any reason? You button will show `r` letter using the default font.

Comment: @JQSOFT - how would I draw it then? Using the onPaint method or something?

Comment: Visual Studio uses a WPF window and draws its own controls. The close button (X) is just a [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.path) with data set to `F1M8.583,8L13,12.424 12.424,13 8,8.583 3.576,13 3,12.424 7.417,8 3,3.576 3.576,3 8,7.417 12.424,3 13,3.576z`. I'm not sure what needs to be done in WinForms to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Exactly mate. Just override the `Paint` event and `e.graphics.drawline` couple of lines.

Comment: Another way if you prefer using the `Marlett` font is to add it as a resource in your project and use it as [Private Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-private-font-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on comments above by [JQSOFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10216583/jqsoft) and [Herohtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574531/herohtar) I've tried to draw the controls on my buttons.  I created a class called CloseButton which inherits from Button, and modified the onPaint method as follows:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        GraphicsPath gPath;
        Pen gPen;
        gPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText);
        gPath = new GraphicsPath();
        gPath.AddLine(20, 10, 30, 20);
        gPath.CloseFigure();
        gPath.AddLine(20, 20, 30, 10);
        gPath.CloseFigure();
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(gPen, gPath);
    }
```

The button looks like this:

[image]

All I need to do now is figure out how to redraw the graphics when I move the mouse over the control (and the colour changes) but I'll get there!